# Javascript Alert in Rails app - checkbox for params hash

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a Rails app that's using an external api for authentication.  If the the same login credentials are used simultaneously the app has to alert the second user that there's already a session in progress.  This needs to be a JavaScript alert with an 'ok' box, and the return has to be passed to the api as a flag to kill the first session.

I've got ideas for parts of it, but it's not coming together.

A hidden input in the login form that's triggered by the alert box?

I also tried this for the alert, but I'm unsure of how to pass 'msg' into the JavaScript, and this doesn't even address the params issue.

```
login_controller.rb

  elsif body['ValidationMessage'] == 'OtherSessionActive'
    flash[:alert] = auth_config['session_alert']
    redirect_to login_path and return
  else

login.html.erb

  <div id='flash'>
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
        <% if name == :alert %>
            <script>
                alert(#{msg})
            </script>
        <% else %>
            <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Got the alert done.  Wasn't using the erb javascript_tag.  I'm thinking use jquery to get the value of the alert box and pass that to a hidden input.  Or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

A way (but not good practice) is following:

```
<div id='flash'>
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
        <% if name == :alert %>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                $(function(){ // if you are using jquery
                   alert("<%= msg %>")
                })

            </script>
        <% else %>
            <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

My preferred way is:
use the following gem:
https://github.com/gazay/gon

You can assign message to javascript object from controller. And can show alert directly from your javascript file.

Comment: Why is this approach not good practice?  My main issue now is, whether I use this gem or not, I still need get data from the alert (I'm actually using confirm) into a params hash so I can use it in a controller action.

Comment: never mind it is pretty ambigious and practicing js inside view and ruby blocks are discouraged

Comment: Also if you look the current context, you will see some ambigious error message even when you generate error message like while you are updating a record ftom controller or creating or any other erroor message will prompt alert. Which might not be the business intended.

Comment: So if you pass the message seperately to js and if you handle the alert message from js then your current flash notification can be used for notification only.